# STM32F411RE: The program freeze and the ultrasonic sensor doesn't work

Tags: c++, stm32, microprocessors, stm32f4, platformio

I have a program in C using the STM32F411RE board, and I can't launch it, it freeze when i debug it, but it worked before I made some little changes. But when it worked, the ultrasonic sensor, didn't recognize any object when it should. The thing is that the code is very similar to other program that do similar things and work perfectly, but here i doesn't, and I can't find a solution.

The program consist in a semaphore that activates a sequence when the sensor detects an object at 200mm. The sequence is the less important, the thing is the sensor, which calculates if there are any object with the function *ultrasonidos*, but i can't even reach this line because the program freeze or something, even when I debug it. It should turn on two leds with this two lines:

```
HAL_Delay(1000);
GPIOB->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD6_Msk;
GPIOA->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD7_Msk;
```

but not even that. Here is the full code:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2019 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim11;
int pulsado = 0;
int contador = 0;
int volatile times = 0;
int cercanos = 0;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM11_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
  int modo = 0;
  int control = 0;
  int counter_parpadeo = 0;
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */
  void ultrasonidos();
  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM11_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim11);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    GPIOB->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD6_Msk; //Encender Verde Coches
    GPIOA->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD7_Msk; //Encender Rojo Peatones
    printf("SE INICIA Y SE PONEN EL VERDE DE COCHES Y EL ROJO DE PEATONES");
    printf("VA A ACTIVAR EL ULTRASONIDOS");
    ultrasonidos();
    printf("SE HA ACTIVADO EL ULTRASONIDOS");
    if (cercanos == 1)
    {
      printf("SE HAN DETECTADO OBJETOS CERCANOS");
      modo = 1;
      control = 1;
      counter_parpadeo = 0;
      while (control == 1)
      {
        switch (modo)
        {
        case 1:
          printf("SE INICIA EL CICLO");
          counter_parpadeo = 0;
          GPIOB->ODR &= ~GPIO_ODR_OD6_Msk; //Apagar verde coches
          GPIOC->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD7_Msk;  //Encender amarillo coches
          printf("AMARILLO COCHES");
          HAL_Delay(5000);
          modo = 2;
          break;
        case 2:
          printf("SEGUNDO FASE");
          GPIOC->ODR &= ~GPIO_ODR_OD7_Msk; //Apagar amarillo coches
          GPIOA->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD9_Msk;  //Encender rojo coches
          GPIOA->ODR &= ~GPIO_ODR_OD7_Msk; //Apagamos rojo peatones
          GPIOA->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD6_Msk;  //Encender verde peatones
          printf("VERDE PEATONES");
          HAL_Delay(5000);
          modo = 3;
          break;
        case 3:
        printf("TERCERA FASE");
          while (counter_parpadeo < 3)
          {
            GPIOA->ODR &= ~GPIO_ODR_OD6_Msk; //Apagar verde peatones
            HAL_Delay(100);
            GPIOA->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD6_Msk; //Encender verde peatones
            HAL_Delay(100);
            counter_parpadeo++;
          }
          printf("PARPADEO");
          HAL_Delay(5000);
          modo = 4;
          break;
        case 4:
          printf("CUARTA FASE");
          GPIOA->ODR &= ~GPIO_ODR_OD6_Msk; //Apagar verde peatones
          GPIOA->ODR &= ~GPIO_ODR_OD9_Msk; //Apagar rojo coches
          GPIOB->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD6_Msk;  //Encendemos verde coches
          GPIOA->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD7_Msk;  //Encendemos rojo peatones
          printf("VERDE COCHES");
          HAL_Delay(5000);
          modo = 1;
          control = 0;
          pulsado = 0;
          cercanos = 0;
          times = 0;
          break;
        }
      }
      /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    }
    HAL_Delay(5000);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief TIM11 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM11_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM11_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM11_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM11_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM11_Init 1 */
  htim11.Instance = TIM11;
  htim11.Init.Prescaler = 83;
  htim11.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim11.Init.Period = 9;
  htim11.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  //htim11.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim11) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM11_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM11_Init 2 */
}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */
}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, LD2_Pin | VerdeP_Pin | RojoP_Pin | RojoC_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(AmarilloC_GPIO_Port, AmarilloC_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(VerdeC_GPIO_Port, VerdeC_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : LD2_Pin VerdeP_Pin RojoP_Pin RojoC_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD2_Pin | VerdeP_Pin | RojoP_Pin | RojoC_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : AmarilloC_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = AmarilloC_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(AmarilloC_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA8 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : Boton_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = Boton_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(Boton_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : VerdeC_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = VerdeC_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(VerdeC_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* EXTI interrupt init*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI15_10_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
/*void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
  __disable_irq();
  if (GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_10)
    pulsado = 1;
  __enable_irq();
}*/

void cambiarModoPin(int modo)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if (modo == 0) //Output
  {
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
  }
  else if (modo == 1) //Input
  {
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
  }
}

int __io_putchar(int ch)
{
  uint8_t c[1];
  c[0] = ch & 0x00FF;
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, &*c, 1, 100);
  return ch;
}

int _write(int file, char *ptr, int len)
{
  int DataIdx;
  for (DataIdx = 0; DataIdx < len; DataIdx++)
  {
    __io_putchar(*ptr++);
  }
  return len;
}

int calcularDistanciaCm(int veces)
{
  int distancia = 0;
  distancia = (veces * 10) / 58;
  printf("CALCULA DISTANCIA:");
  printf("%d", distancia);
  return distancia;
}

void ultrasonidos()
{
  int times2 = 0;
  int times3 = 0;
  cambiarModoPin(0); //Modo output
  times = 0;
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  printf("SE METE EN EL ULTRASONIDO");

  while(times >= 1){
    printf("DENTRO DEL WHILE DEL TIMES:");
    printf("%d", times);
  }
  printf("TIMES 1:");
  printf("%d", times);
  cambiarModoPin(1); //Modo Input

  while(!(GPIOA->IDR & GPIO_IDR_ID8_Msk)){

  }
  times2 = times;
  printf("TIMES 2:");
  printf("%d", times2);
  while((GPIOA->IDR & GPIO_IDR_ID8_Msk)) {

  }
  times3 = times;
  printf("TIMES 3:");
  printf("%d", times3);
    if (calcularDistanciaCm(times3-times2) < 20) {
        printf("HAY OBJETOS CERCA");
        cercanos = 1;
    }
  
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  if (htim->Instance == TIM11)
  {
    printf("SALTA LA EXCEPCION PARA SUMAR LOS TIMES");
    times++;
  }
}

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Comment: I recommend backing up your code and then carving what you have down to a smaller program that reproduces the bug you're looking for. You will find few people here interesting in digging through 500 lines of code for a bug, and if you isolate the bug to the point where folk will be helpful, odds are really good you'll have already found and fixed the bug. If not, you're either missing a little bit of information or have a really sneaky problem that deserves to be solved and recorded for future programmers to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

For the program Freeze issue, if freeze happens at HAL_Delay(100), it means that Systick Interrupt is not enabled which causes an infinite loop inside HAL_Delay.

Add this statement after SystemClock_Config() to enable Systick interrupt.

```
SET_BIT(SysTick->CTRL, SysTick_CTRL_TICKINT_Msk);
```

As for the Ultrasonic sensor, I am not sure which sensor you're using, HC SR04 has two pins one for trigger(Output pin) and one for echo(input pin). Even if you require a single GPIO, rather than changing pin type to input configure the GPIO as an open drain, that way you can set trigger and read at then read echo response.
Let me know the results.

Comment: With SET_BIT it could debug, and I have the ultrasonic sensor function commented by now to see what happens, but it gets stucked again in these lines:
`
GPIOB->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD6_Msk; 
GPIOA->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD7_Msk;`

when the while begins, after HAL_Delay(1000);

And the sensor is like an HC-SR04 but instead of trigger and the echo, it has just a signal pin.

Comment: While debugging you can check the changes to GPIOB from the SFR window, make sure the LEDs are configured correctly as output, you can also try the HAL_GPIO_TogglePin function to toggle output pins. For further reference, check the reference manual https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00119316-stm32f411xc-e-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf.

For the ultrasonic sensor, try to find the part number or source from where you bought it. In any case, changing I/O mode is not a good idea, it is best done with Open-drain mode, otherwise you can end up with damaged pins

Comment: I couldn't find the part number, but this is the sensor i'm using: https://www.seeedstudio.com/Ultra-Sonic-range-measurement-module-p-626.html

Comment: Apparently it fixed by taken de HAL_DELAY(1000) inside the if (cercanos == 1), and removing:
HAL_Delay(1000);
    GPIOB->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD6_Msk; 
    GPIOA->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD7_Msk;

But now, it only work for an specific amount of times, and then it will execute the loop forever without the sensor catching anything.